# Upload a file to an API using cy.request

Tags: testing, cypress

I am doing functional tests with Cypress to an API via cy.request, I need to create a test in which I upload a file inside the cy.request and the API answers me a 200.

Comment: So what did you manage to write on your own?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For the community to help can you provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? For more guidance on well constructed questions check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.